# How to say "You are lying!"

Tags: slang, phrase-requests, jokes

How do I say "You are lying!" in a joking way?

Can I say:

> 嘘{うそ}だよ

or is there a friendlier way to say it?

Comment: [異議あり!](https://www.google.com/search?q=異議あり)

Comment: @Flaw I see a pretty unfortunate typo...

Comment: @broccoliforest Ah! *abuses editing powers*... You didn't see anything!

Answer (score 10):

Another is:

[うそつけ (嘘{うそ}吐{つ}け)](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91)！ - Liar! Comes from 嘘｛うそ｝をつく, to lie

From comments:

[うそつき (嘘{うそ}吐{つ}き)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/19011/meaning/m0u/) - Liar; Someone who lies

Comment: You also have 嘘吐き.

Comment: うそつけ！ would be fine to use jokingly among close friends, but うそつき！ doesn't really sound friendly and may be too serious/harsh...

Comment: Just a minor comment, but 吐｛つ｝く is not normally used; hiragana is the common writing for it. People will be able to read it though

Answer (score 9):

嘘だよ is likely to mean "*I am* joking." One way to say "you are lying" is to use an interrogative form:

> 嘘だろ！？ / 冗談だろ！？
>
> Isn't that a joke?
>
> マジかよ！？
>
> Really!?

Examples above are very casual. Of course we can make them formal by using 敬語:

> 嘘ですよね？ / 冗談ですよね？
>
> 本当ですか？
>
> (note that マジ is a casual saying of 本当).

If we use a normal sentence, it might sound in a strong tone, so not friendly:

> 嘘だ。 / 嘘だろ。
>
> It's a lie. 　 (it may sound like "It's *definitely* a lie.")

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a little more indirect:

> 違{ちが}います！

Often translated as “it’s different”, it’s also used for “just kidding” or “that’s incorrect”.

In Japanese culture, people rarely confront each other or directly disagree. Most of the time, they will correct a misunderstanding rather than disagree.

Comment: I would argue that 違います is closer to "You're mistaken," which is inherently different from "You're lying."